# How do I tell pip to install from git if older than a specified version

Tags: python, git, pip, pypi

Packages published to PYPI can be installed with something like

```
pip install 'foo>=3.0.0'
```

How how to tell pip to install unreleased version from a git url by keeping the same version condition?

This is important when you need to use an unreleased version but you don't want to force using unreleased versions all the time.

```
 pip install git+https://github.com/org/foó.git
```

To be clear: you found a bug in current release and managed to get the bug fixed and merged into master but you need to wait till the next release.

How can you achieve this?

Please note that I am talking about a library that I do not own: so I cannot release it myself and I am not able to add tags to it.

Still, I don't want to fork it, I just want to install it from git till the new release appears. Ideally I should not change my code after the dependency is released.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ pip install --pre --no-cache-dir git+https://github.com/{OWNER}/{REPO}.git@{HASH}
```

The command without --pre option below will not work as expected:

```
$ pip install --no-cache-dir git+https://github.com/{OWNER}/{REPO}.git@{HASH}
```